# Why can't i use Click in Storyboard

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to implement a change of the Click Event when Snapped_detail happens but I cant seem to do it this way..? how else do i modify the click event of the back button? 
Here is my code:

```
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Click">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="snapped_back_click"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

And this is the rest of it.

```
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="primaryColumn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetail" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetail" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="titlePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetailTitlePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetailTitlePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetail" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="20,0,20,0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemDetailGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,60"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register to `Window.Current.SizeChanged` event instead

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;
```

and than in your `WindowSizeChanged` function assign the different function to button

```
    private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if(ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
          {
               backButton.Click += snapped_back_click;
          }
          else
          {
               //something else
          }
    }
```